# How can I make the A* algorithm give me the shortest path? (see picture enclosed)

Tags: c++, a-star

I use Justin Heyes-Jones implementation of the astar algorithm. My heuristic function is just Euclidean distance. In the drawing attached (sorry for bad quality) a specific situation is described: lets say we are going from the node 1 to the node 2. The shortest way would go through the nodes a - b - c - d - e. But the step-by-step Astar with the Euclidean heuristic will give us the way through the following nodes: a - b' - c' - d' - e and I understand why this happens. But what do I have to do to make it return the shortest path?!

[false shortest path finding by the astar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfL1C.jpg)

The code for the real road map import:

```
#include "search.h"

class ArcList;

class MapNode
{
public:

    int x, y;       // ���������� ����
    MapNode();
    MapNode(int X, int Y);
    float Get_h( const MapNode & Goal_node );
    bool GetNeighbours( AStarSearch<MapNode> *astarsearch, MapNode *parent_node );
    bool IsSamePosition( const MapNode &rhs );
    void PrintNodeInfo() const;

    bool operator == (const MapNode & other) const;

    void setArcList( ArcList * list );

private:
    ArcList * list;
};

class Arc
{
public:
    MapNode A1;
    MapNode B1;
    Arc(const MapNode & a, const MapNode & b);
};

class ArcList
{
public:

    void setArcs( const std::vector<Arc> & arcs );
    void addArc( const Arc & arc );

    size_t size() const;

    bool addNeighbours( AStarSearch<MapNode> * astarsearch, const MapNode & neighbour );

private :
    std::vector<Arc> arcs;
};

std::vector <MapNode> FindPath(const MapNode & StartNode, const MapNode & GoalNode)
{
    AStarSearch<MapNode> astarsearch;
    astarsearch.SetStartAndGoalStates( StartNode, GoalNode );

    unsigned int SearchState;
    unsigned int SearchSteps = 0;

    do
    {
        if ( SearchSteps % 100 == 0)
            std::cout << "making step " << SearchSteps << endl;

        SearchState = astarsearch.SearchStep();

        SearchSteps++;
    }
    while ( SearchState == AStarSearch<MapNode>::SEARCH_STATE_SEARCHING );

    std::vector<MapNode> S;
    if ( SearchState == AStarSearch<MapNode>::SEARCH_STATE_SUCCEEDED )
    {
        int steps = 0;

        for ( MapNode * node = astarsearch.GetSolutionStart(); node != 0; node = astarsearch.GetSolutionNext() )
        {
            S.push_back(*node);
//            node->PrintNodeInfo();
        }

        astarsearch.FreeSolutionNodes();
    }
    else if ( SearchState == AStarSearch<MapNode>::SEARCH_STATE_FAILED )
    {
        throw " SEARCH_FAILED ";
    }
    return S;
}
```

Function FindPath gives me the vector of the result nodes.

Here is addNeighbours method:

```
bool ArcList::addNeighbours( AStarSearch<MapNode> * astarsearch, const MapNode & target )
{
    assert(astarsearch != 0);
    bool found = false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arcs.size(); i++ )
    {
        Arc arc = arcs.at(i);

        if (arc.A1 == target)
        {
            found = true;
            astarsearch->AddSuccessor( arc.B1 );
        }
        else if (arc.B1 == target )
        {
            found = true;
            astarsearch->AddSuccessor( arc.A1 );
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

and get_h method:

```
float MapNode::Get_h( const MapNode & Goal_node )
{
    float dx = x - Goal_node.x;
    float dy = y - Goal_node.y;
    return ( dx * dx  + dy * dy );
}
```

I know that its not exact distance (no taking of square root here) - this is done to save some machine resources when evaluating.

Comment: Can we see your code so we can find out what's going wrong?

Comment: Is the arc length the squared distance as well?

Comment: Yap, but I dont really use it. See all I have as an input is a list of arcs. Thats where I take the info about the nodes and there neighbours from. There is no need to evaluate arcs lengths cauze I have g(x) function for every node I pass. Correct me please if I am wrong

Comment: That way you're doing best first search and not A*. Point of A* is taking the value to be distanceSoFar + heurisitc. The openSet is sorted by this value. If you don't calculate the cost it takes you to get from the initial state to the current node, you can get results that are not optimal.

Comment: I thought line #272 in stlastar.h does this for me : float newg = n->g + n->m_UserState.GetCost( (*successor)->m_UserState );

Comment: Its a fun thing that when I go backwards through those points (I mean when I swap start and goal nodes) it gives me the correct answer..

Comment: That's really strange. Yes that line does it for you, but do you pass the correct cost in there, i.e. the square of the actual distance? And do you always generate all the neighbours? You should do some debugging and try to localize the problem, 'cos it seems like it will be some bug in your code. And is the arc length between the nodes always greater than their euclidean distance? I can imagine that if you take the data from a real map, there can be some imprecision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using A* graph search, i.e. you only consider the first visit to a node and disregard the future visits, this can in fact happen when your heuristic is not consistent. If the heuristic is not consistent and you use a graph search, (you keep a list of visited states and if you have already encountered a state, you do not expand it again), your search doesn't give the correct answer.

However, when you use A* tree search with an admissible heuristic, you should get the correct answer. The difference in tree and graph search is that in the tree search you expand the state every time you encounter it. Hence even if at first your algorithm decides to take the longer b', c', d' path, later it returns to a, expands it again and finds out that the b, c, d path is in fact shorter.

Hence my advice is, either to use the tree search instead of the graph search, or choose a consistent heuristic.

For definition of consistent, see for example: [Wikipedia: A* Search Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)

EDIT: While the above is still true, this heuristic is indeed consistent, I apologise for the confusion.

EDIT2: While the heuristic itself is admissible and consistent, the implementation wasn't. For the sake of performance you decided not to do the square root and that made your heuristic inadmissible and it was the reason why you got wrong results.

For the future, it is always better to first implement your algorithms as naively as possible. It usually helps to keep them more readable and they are less prone to bugs. If there are bugs, they are easier to spot. Hence, my final advice would be don't optimise unless you need it, or unless everything else is working well. Otherwise you may get into troubles.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please give an example of a consistent heuristic function that could be used for real road maps if you know any?

Comment: Now this is a bit awkward, looking at it again, I think your heuristic is indeed consistent. Hence the error must be somewhere else. Can you post your code? Does it work when you use the tree search? In theory this should give you the correct answer, hence there must be an error in the implementation.

Comment: The code itself is pretty big. You can find it here http://code.google.com/p/a-star-algorithm-implementation/downloads/list. I just changed the way of getting the nodes from a map but i have not changed anything in the search template. By the way how do you change from graph search to a tree A* search? Just delete the closed list or not?

Comment: What have you changed exactly? I am not using C++ very often, but from what I can tell they are using Manhattan Distance, not Euclidean. Are you sure you are using Euclidean distance? And do you allow diagonal moves? Because if you are using Manhattan distance and allow diagonal moves, then we are back to the beginning and this heuristic is not consistent.

Comment: And yes, not using the closed list will give you a tree search instead of graph search.

Comment: I have taken the stlsearch.h file and created my own .h file that can work with the real road map not game maps. I have added the code to the question block.

Comment: I cannot see the code, can you add it again? Make sure you use the correct formatting.

Comment: @Starter You had added the code to the *answer*, which was why it did not show. Please be a bit more careful next time.

Comment: Sorry for that.. Here you go.

Comment: Can you post the Get_h and GetNeighbours code as well? This is just calling the functions in the original implementation, which looks like it should work.

Comment: Hi! I can't tell from the code above whether your heuristic is admissible or not because I don't see how you get the arc distance. One thing to check is that you are squaring the arc distance, since you are squaring your estimated distance. Or for ease of testing just stick a sqrt in there at first.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that taking the square root in get_h method has solved it. Turns out that my heuristic wasnt admissable (at least I think this explains it). Special thanks to Laky and justinhj for helping out with this!!!

Comment: If you want to thank me, you can always put a checkmark next to my answer ;) I will edit it a little bit to reflect what happened in the end.